# Write a linq query with many to many scenario and other table

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql, fluent, entity-framework-migrations

I want to write a linq query that join some tables and return a custom object but I have some problems with the many to many table because I do not have any object to work with. You will see at the end my problematic linq query but for now let's me show you what I have with Code First, fluent API and SQL:

Here are all tables I need to work with (you will see all foreign keys with the sql statement later):

1. **UserProfile**
2. **BusinessProfile**
3. **Bid**
4. **Tender**
5. **UserBusinessProfile** *Many to many table for user and business profile*

The many to many table is define within `protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)` this way

```
// Many to many UserProfiles => BusinessProfiles
            modelBuilder.Entity<UserProfile>()
                .HasKey(primaryKey => primaryKey.Id)
                .HasMany(business => business.BusinessProfiles)
                .WithMany(user => user.UserProfiles)
                .Map(m => m.MapLeftKey("UserProfileId")
                .MapRightKey("BusinessProfileId")
                .ToTable("UserBusinessProfile"));
```

Right here, the .ToTable("UserBusinessProfile") I need to include in my linq query...

Finally, my **SQL Statement** I need to write with linq (SQL Statement work as expected.):

```
select * from UserProfile inner join UserBusinessProfile on UserProfile.Id = UserBusinessProfile.UserProfileId inner join BusinessProfile on BusinessProfile.Id = UserBusinessProfile.BusinessProfileId inner join Bid on Bid.UserProfileId = UserProfile.Id and Bid.BusinessProfileId = BusinessProfile.Id inner join Tender on Bid.TenderId = Tender.Id
```

And the linq query I have:

```
from UserProfile in context.UserProfile
join UserBusinessProfile in context.UserBusinessProfile on new { Id = UserProfile.Id } equals new { Id = UserBusinessProfile.UserProfileId }
join BusinessProfile in context.BusinessProfile on new { Id = UserBusinessProfile.BusinessProfileId } equals new { Id = BusinessProfile.Id }
join Bid in context.Bid
      on new { UserProfileId = UserProfile.Id, BusinessProfileId = BusinessProfile.Id }
  equals new { Bid.UserProfileId, Bid.BusinessProfileId }
join Tender in context.Tender on new { TenderId = Bid.TenderId } equals new { TenderId = Tender.Id }
where
  UserProfile.Id == 1 &&
  BusinessProfile.Id == 1
select new CustomObject{
  ...
}
```

As you can see, I cannot use context.UserBusinessProfile from my linq query because I do not have any object to work with like the other table. And I really don't know how I can do that or how I can write my linq query to make things done.

Thank you for your time and your help,

Karine

---

In other words, how can I write the linq query from this SQL query when you know that UserBusinessProfile is the many to many table??:

```
select * from UserProfile 
inner join UserBusinessProfile on UserProfile.Id = UserBusinessProfile.UserProfileId
inner join BusinessProfile on BusinessProfile.Id = UserBusinessProfile.BusinessProfileId
inner join Bid on Bid.UserProfileId = UserProfile.Id and Bid.BusinessProfileId = BusinessProfile.Id
inner join Tender on Bid.TenderId = Tender.Id
where UserProfile.Id = 1 and BusinessProfile.Id = 1
```

Comment: This can help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201799/code-first-mvc-4-ef-5-many-to-many-join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to go. May be it could be optimize but its working.

```
    from user in context.UserProfiles
                    from business in context.BusinessProfiles
                    join bid in context.Bids on new { UserProfileId = user.Id, BusinessProfileId = business.Id } equals new { bid.UserProfileId, bid.BusinessProfileId }
                    join tender in context.Tenders on new { TenderId = bid.TenderId } equals new { TenderId = tender.Id }
                    where business.Id == businessProfileId && user.Id == userProfileId && tender.Id == tenderId
select new CustomObject
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be much easier to write in LINQ.

```
from ubp in context.UserBusinessProfile 
where ubp.UserProfile.Id = 1 && ubp.BusinessProfile.Id = 1
select ubp.UserProfile
//you can pretty much do anything with Bid and Tender, 
//you should be able to access Bid from
//ubp.BusinessProfile.Bids 
//(I think multiple bids are available for a BusinessProfile)
```

Comment: I can't use context.UserBusinessProfile because it's the many to many table .ToTable("UserBusinessProfile")); I don't have the object for that table like UserProfile or BusinessProfile in the context:(

Comment: Shouldn't you have it though? Without that entity/poco correctly set up you will have trouble writing queries since you won't be able to generate right SQL.

Comment: Do you have an example? Where can I configure that correctly? I use Code first migration with fluent api and the only place I see is in the OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) function.